# preciso formatar data para Brasil em laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Olá,

Preciso mostrar a data 00-00-0000 como faço nesse código abaixo?

```
<span data-bind="text: created_at"></span>
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar esse padrão de data, você pode utilizar a função nativa do PHP, a **[Date](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)** ou o **[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/)** (classe padrão que o Laravel utiliza para data), que já vem instalado no Laravel.

No controle utilize como exemplo o código abaixo. Adicione `$user->created_at->format("d-m-Y")`. Ex:

```
public function index()
{        
    $reviews = \App\Reviews::all();

    return view('home', ["reviews" => $reviews]);
}
```

Na view utilize

```
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
<span data-bind="text: {{ $review->created_at->format("d-m-Y") }}"></span>
@endforeach
```

Caso queira alterar o formato, basta substituir **d-m-Y** por qualquer um dos valores da tabela a seguir: http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: Olá Valdeir, obrigado.

mas esta dando o seguinte erro

Undefined variable: created_at

Comment: Você está usando blade? Você está passando a variável `created_at` em um array para a view? Se possível edite sua pergunta com os trechos do seu código.

Comment: Sim, blade

coloquei como me orientou

public function index()
    {
        $users = Reviews::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('reviews'));
  
   $user = \App\User::find(1);

    $data["created_at"] = $user->created_at->format("d-m-Y");

    return view('home', $data);
    }

no blade

<span data-bind="text: {{ $created_at }}"></span>

Comment: @Toninho, alterei meu exemplo.

Comment: Undefined variable: reviews

Comment: @Toninho, você precisa adaptar o meu exemplo ao seu código. Como não tenho o código fonte do seu projeto, posso apenas analisar superficialmente. Se possível **edite sua pergunta** com parte de seu código fonte. Esse erro é na view, controller... ?

Comment: coloquei no view index.blade.php igual o que me passou. O erro é no index.blade.php

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, se possível verifica novamente.

Comment: parte do index.blade

<section data-bind="foreach: {data: sourceItems, afterRender: lazyLoadImage}" class="col-sm-8">

       Publicado: <span data-bind="text: created_at"></span><br>

Comment: Undefined variable: reviews

Comment: Posta sua `view` na sua pergunta (e não apenas uma linha dela), senão fica difícil. É tanto que você, provavelmente, está utilizando `knockoutjs` (ou similar) e não deixou claro na pergunta. Só assimilei agora. Sem informações não tem como auxiliar muito.